# How to convert existing rails application to gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have a rails application that is kind of similar to the `active_admin` gem. I want to make this existing application into a gem.

I know that you can generate a gem with:

```
bundler gem gem_name_here
```

This command creates an empty gem. Which is fine I suppose, I just don't know where to put all my code.

You're ostensibly supposed to put all of your code in the `/lib` directory. However, my application has an assets pipeline and an `app` directory with all my models, controllers, and views. I don't know where to place all of these directories in the gem. Any thoughts or ideas?

If you need me to share any code, I'll gladly share it.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're describing a rails engine. Engine is a miniature rails application that can be used inside other rails app. For more details see [official rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)